# Is there a css page URL selector?

Tags: css

In a scenario where I do not have control over the markup generation, the classes are named the same in multiple pages, but I want to style them differently, based by the page which they are at.

How to do that without changing the html AND without resorting to js?

Comment: Short answer: no. *But..* if you had a slight change in the html between the pages, that can be enough, for example a class added to the `body` tag or another parent container. If you're lucky, there is already one, if not, it's a minor thing to add

Comment: Another short answer is, [only in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @MrLister one of the only times I see Firefox implementing solutions for non-problems like this, but great, I didn't know this one

Comment: I think the firefox solution is not targeted to a non-problem itself, although it can be the case here, but more like an improvement to broaden the selectors, which is even greater

Comment: I see this as a non-problem because different URLs can request different CSS files, of even have different `style` tags hardcoded in their source. I see no really useful case for this selector. Maybe a rare case where CSS is hosted on another domain and you can access only this domain for editing, but I see no useful reason to do this either